# How to return a default value if subquery doesn't provide any output {Oracle}

Tags: sql, oracle, default

How to provide a default output if my subquery doesnt provide anyput?

```
select Id 
from (select ID, 
             rank() over (partition by salary order by ID) as rw_num 
      from emp
     ) a 
where a.rw_num > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use exception handling with the case option `no_data_found` within PL/SQL :

```
declare
  v_id emp.id%type;
begin
  select Id
    into v_id
    from (select ID, rank() over(partition by salary order by ID) as rw_num
            from emp) a
   where a.rw_num > 10
 exception when no_data_found then v_id := 0;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for you comment, is there a way to do in the SQL query and not in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` with desired "default" output might help.

The "original" subquery is now the `data` CTE. The first `SELECT` (line #6) returns rows that satisfy the condition (for `rw_num` value). It is then `UNION`ed with another `SELECT` (line #10) which uses `NOT EXISTS` with the same condition (for `rw_num`) as previously.

If there are certain rows that satisfy the condition:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     data
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT ename, RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY sal) rw_num
  5           FROM emp)
  6  SELECT ename
  7    FROM data
  8   WHERE rw_num > &&n
  9  UNION
 10  SELECT 'Nothing has been found'
 11    FROM DUAL
 12   WHERE NOT EXISTS
 13            (SELECT NULL
 14               FROM data
 15              WHERE rw_num > &&n);
Enter value for n: 4

ENAME
----------------------
ALLEN
BLAKE
```

If there are not:

```
SQL> undefine n
SQL> /
Enter value for n: 10

ENAME
----------------------
Nothing has been found

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks!! Can we do something without union? probably in the case statement or something like that ?

Comment: You're welcome. If query doesn't return anything ("no rows selected"), you have to take the "default" value from somewhere. CASE won't help, nor would NVL because it is not that a "value" is missing - the whole "row" is missing.